# pin interest kind layout: box get broke down

Tags: css, html

I am trying pin interest kind layout.

```html
   <div id="container" class="cols">
     <div class="box one">1</div>
     <div class="box two">2</div>
     <div class="box one">3</div>
     <div class="box two">4</div>
  </div>
```

```css
 #container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 2em auto;
}
.cols {
-moz-column-fill: balance;
-moz-column-count:3;
-moz-column-gap: 3%;
-moz-column-width: 30%;

-webkit-column-fill: balance;
-webkit-column-count:3;
-webkit-column-gap: 3%;
-webkit-column-width: 30%;

column-count: 3;
column-gap: 3%;
column-width: 30%;
column-fill: balance;

 overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
   height: 200px;
}
.box.one {
  background-color: #d77575;
}
.box.two {   
  background-color: #dcbc4c;
}
```

with some tutorials from internet i manged to get some thing like this. 
http://jsfiddle.net/LnG7v/

But the problem is boxes gets broke down to get align with layout. 
If you notices box 2 and box 3 is broken in the example. 
how to get the same layout without breaking the boxes.

Comment: You need [masonary](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try Isotope or Packery. It allows you to create grid layouts that always fill the empty spaces.

http://packery.metafizzy.co/

or

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/